Downloading S3 object on Android with Kotlin and hardcoded credentials
I know that hardcoded creds are a big no no.
But I want to write an app just for me. No one else would get this app.
So I wanted to put my accessKey and secretKey directly into the code so that the app will be able to download files from my s3 bucket.
Edit:
So now I'm at this state:
runBlocking {
            val s3 = S3Client.fromEnvironment {
                credentialsProvider = StaticCredentialsProvider(Credentials("some-access-key", "some-secret-key"))
                region = "some-region"
            }

            try {
                val getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest {
                    bucket = "some-bucket"
                    key = "some-key"
                }

                val response: GetObjectResponse = s3.getObject(
                    getObjectRequest
                )

                println("File downloaded successfully")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Error downloading file: ${e.message}")
            } finally {
                s3.close()
            }
        }

and on the getObjectRequest Android Studio states No value passed for parameter 'block'.
I'm not sure how to proceed.

Add the AWS SDK to your project and you should find functions and classes you can use in there
